# How can I draw text on a D3 SVG iff it's bounding box falls within certain criteria?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm using D3.js to draw some text onto an SVG Container.
While drawing the text, I translate its position somewhat.
I store the translated x-position of the left boundary of the text in a variable called `a`

```
    var a = null;

    var label = svgContainer.append("text")
      .attr("x", 200)
      .attr("y", 300)
      .text("Hello World")
      .attr("font-family", "Courier New")
      .attr("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("font-size", "10px")
      .attr("fill", "black")
      .attr("transform", function(d){
          var bb = this.getBBox();
          console.log("bb.x = ", bb.x);
          console.log("bb.y = ", bb.y);
          console.log("bb.width = ", bb.width);
          console.log("bb.height = ", bb.height);
          a = bb.x - (bb.width/2);
          return "translate(" + (bb.width / (-2)) + ", 0)";
        }
      );
```

I want to change this code such that it draws the text *if and only if* the `a < 100`. How can I do it? The problem is that a is only calculated and assigned a value while the text is being drawn. By that time it is too late. How do I get the value *before* actually drawing the text??

Comment: Just a suggestion. make text opacity 0. and check the value of a after drawing text. if it is less than 0 then make opacity 1. or else remove the text `label.remove()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add: `.style("display", "none")` after getting the BBox:

```
   var a = null;

    var label = svgContainer.append("text")
      .attr("x", 100)
      .attr("y", 10)
      .text("Hello World")
      .attr("font-family", "Courier New")
      .attr("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("font-size", "10px")
      .attr("fill", "black")
      .attr("transform", function(d){
          var bb = this.getBBox();
          console.log("bb.x = ", bb.x);
          console.log("bb.y = ", bb.y);
          console.log("bb.width = ", bb.width);
          console.log("bb.height = ", bb.height);
          a = bb.x - (bb.width/2);
          return "translate(" + (bb.width / (-2)) + ", 0)";
        }
      )
      .style("display", "none");
```

and then use: `svgContainer.selectAll("text")`

```
svgContainer.selectAll("text")
               .attr("x", function(d) {
                 // enter your code/ validations in here        
                  })
                  .style("display", "block");
```